# Create isolines shape-file by Geotools

Tags: geotools

I have an array (grid) of points (coordinates x,y and attribute top). I need to build isolines by them (basis of attribute top values) and create a shape-file.

I use Geotools Java library and I'm able create a shape-file with set of LineString. But unfortunately I have no idea what to do with my array of point to get isolines.

**Does Geotools have a way to build isolines automatically?**

Comment: if you google the text of your question, the second result i get is http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/feature/csv2shp.html

Comment: Thank you, but I know this tutorial and it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoTools considers contouring (which is what we geographers call isolines :-)) to be an imaging operation so it is outsourced to the [JAI-tools](http://jaitools.org/) library.

The basic process is to convert your array of points into an Image and then call the Contouring process on it as a JAI op.

There is a full demo [here](https://github.com/mbedward/jaitools/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/org/jaitools/demo/contour/ContourDemo.java).

Comment: This explanation clarifies the situation :) Thanks for the demo.